# NxN tabluation over columns in R and check duplicacy between columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, dcast

I have a dataframe with unique items procured on rows and their corresponding sources on columns (Basically this is a data which I have "dcast" from original data)

Now it looks like this

DF <- data.frame(Food = c("Burger",
                          "Pizza",
                          "Egg rolls",
                          "Noodles",
                          "Tea",
                          "Coffee",
                          "Biscuits",
                          "Apples",
                          "Bananas"), Source1=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0), Source2=c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1), Source3=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1), Source4=c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)

)

Now based on this dacasted data I have to create a table which checks for duplicay from sources like  this

[This is the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL0uD.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can get it via the following codes:

```
m <- as.matrix(DF[-1])
z <- t(m)%*%m
diag(z) <- NA
```

which gives:

```
> z
        Source1 Source2 Source3 Source4
Source1      NA       2       0       1
Source2       2      NA       2       0
Source3       0       2      NA       0
Source4       1       0       0      NA
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. This worked nicely. Also it would be great help me show this in percentages

Comment: @Vaibhav what is your desired output for percentages?